# Summary statistics in both numerical and nominal dataframes R

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

how will I be able to iterate through the columns of a dataframe to get some summary statistics?

```
>df <- read.csv("myfile", sep='\t')
>
>column <- df$column_name   # How can I implement this part in a loop?
>column.freq = table(x)
```

Also, in some cases, the values at each row are non-numerical data. How will I get a mean that makes sense? Because when I do it manually, I get a return value of `6838.667` which doesn't make any sense in non-numerical data.

Example output:

```
Column: col_name
mean: value (either numerical or nominal)
median: same as above
mode: same as above
dispersion: same as above
```

Comment: Are you trying to re-implement the `summary()` function? What exactly is the desired output?

Comment: @mrFlick I've added an example of desired output. if I use summary, because the data are so many, I can't get a good understanding of what is going on.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I can't post the head(df). my dataframe is 40000*48 it's chaotic to post it.

Comment: There is no existing definition of a "mean", "median", etc. for a categorical variable. It's unclear what you would want to show in that case. Also, is your desired output just a string with line breaks in it? How does it handle multiple columns? This question doesn't seem specific enough to be answerable.

Comment: I would say yes, I need a string with line breaks as an output. It will handle multiple columns since it will in a loop. so for every column It will print the data I need. One way I could think of implementing the `mean` and `median` for categorical values, would be to assign a number to each `different` value in the column and do the computations. but I lack the R background to make this happen. That's why I need help, because after 2 hours of googling I can't find anything :/